# php Project with java

Tags: java, php, web

Our Web Project first was written in PHP, but after that time we have sub 
projects which were written in Java. now we have some data to exchange.

```
    $url = 'http://hr.sankuai.com/mtorg/org/api/mischange?start='. $stime. '&end='. $t. '&token='. $token;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now we always do like this. Such as java have a service, then PHP wants to 
visit the service, then we will call curl function.

We always do like this. I think it's very ugly. Do you have some experience where a project mix with java and php. How can you do when you php want to visit you java service. Or you java project want to visit the php service. Does thrift can solve This problem? Thank you~

Answer (score -2):

You can create a Java Web Service to communicate more efficiently :  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service

Comment: It may have many other advantages, but I highly doubt a web service would be more efficient; SOAP web services certainly wouldn't be, and what he has is basically a dumbed-down REST web service. And that's not counting the extra hassle of implementing it.